# Nature of unit disk's region

Tags: complex-analysis

Reading Garnett's book "Bounded Analytic Functions" I met the following assertion:

> **If $u$ is the Poisson integral of $f$ on $\partial{\mathbb{D}}$, then $$\sup_{z\in\Gamma_{a}(e^{it})}{|u(z)|}<C_a \mathrm{M}f(e^{it}),$$ where $\mathrm{M}f$ is the Hardy-Littlewood
>   maximal function of f, $$\Gamma_{a}(e^{it}):=\left\{ z\in\mathbb{D}: \frac{\left| e^{it}-z \right|}{1-|z|}<a \right\}, \ a>1,$$ and $C_a$ a
>   positive constant depending only on $a$.**

The proof of the assertion above follows the same logic with the proof of the upper half plane case. But my question is what is the nature of the region $\Gamma_{a}(e^{it})$. The respective region in the upper half plane case is the cone
$$\Gamma_a(s):=\left\{ w=x+iy: \frac{|x-s|}{y}<a \right\}.$$
I guess that $\Gamma_{a}(e^{it})$ is probably the image of $\Gamma_{a}(s)$ under the Cayley transform $T(w)=\frac{i-w}{i+w}$, but I don't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

On the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$, there is an intrinsic description of the $\Gamma_a(s)$ as follows:

> Let $\gamma$ be the unique (up to reparametrization) geodesic going from $\infty$ at time $-\infty$ to $s$ at time $+\infty$.
>   Then for some function $\alpha(a)$,
>   $$\Gamma_a(s)=\{z\in\mathbb{H}:\rho(z,\{\gamma(t):t\in\mathbb{R}\})<\alpha(a)\}$$
>   where $\rho$ is the distance function induced by the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{H}$.

Unfortunately the book's formulation of $\Gamma_a(e^{it})$ takes a shortcut that means it is not the corresponding formulation.  It is the intersection of

- $\mathbb{D}$ itself;
- an open cone vertex at $e^{it}$, rotation axis the inward normal at $e^{it}$, apex half-angle depending on $a$ (less than $\pi/2$); and
- a sufficiently small ambient neighbourhood of $e^{it}$.

While this construction would yield the same in the case of upper half plane, it doesn't in $\mathbb{D}$ because the "cone" needs to be curved in $\mathbb{D}$ to get constant geodesic curvature (ambient homothety at boundary in not a hyperbolic isometry in $\mathbb{D}$).  Another way of looking at it: the sloped line $(b+ic)t$ is mapped to a circle via the Cayley transform, but this is precisely what bounds your $\Gamma_a(0)$.